# How can I make my username div expand its width depending on the length of the username?

Tags: html, css

At the moment I have 3 divs inside a parent div. 1 of those divs contains the username which needs to expand its width depending on the length of the name. At the moment my divs just seem to all fall apart whenever I edit my parent wrap div. Anyone know how I can fix this?

this is what im trying to explain

[image]

[image]

My HTML

```
<div id="user_wrap">

<div id="user_welcome">
Welcome <b>Christopher</b>
</div>

<div id="user_logout">
Logout?
</div>

<div id="user_pic">
<img src="images/user_pic.png" width="38" height="37" />
</div>

</div>
```

My CSS

```
#user_wrap{
float: right;
height: 40px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-top: 5px;
position: relative;
width: 190px;
}


#user_welcome{
float: left;
position: relative;
text-align: right;
width: 130px;
font-size: 11.8px;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial;
color: #e3e3e3;
margin-bottom: 3px;
padding-top: 3px;
}

#user_logout{
float: left;
position: relative;
text-align: right;
width: 130px;
font-size: 11.8px;
font-weight: 200;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial;
color: #939393;

}

#user_pic{
border-radius: 5px;
float: left;
height: 37px;
margin-top: -18px;
margin-left: 10px;
width: 38px;

-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px #000000;
box-shadow: 0 1px 4px #000000;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried counting the length of the name and then if it is over a certain threshold changing with width?

Comment: What do you mean by, "fall apart whenever I edit my parent wrap div"?

Comment: Put your example that breaks it in www.jsfiddle.net to see the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't declare a floating element's width, it will automatically scale its width to match the contents, so the first thing to do is to remove the width declarations from the CSS.

Now the problem is that since the username element and the logout element are both floating, they're placed next to each other if the parent element's width isn't constrained. The solution is to remove the float declaration from them and put them both into a new floating parent div:

```
<div id="user_info">
    <div id="user_welcome">
    Welcome <b>Christopher</b>
    </div>

    <div id="user_logout">
    Logout?
    </div>
</div>

#user_info {
    float:left;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bpeZp/